# VirtualBox windows guest can't connect to bluehost email smtp

Tags: virtualbox, email, windows-server-2008, smtp

I have a Windows Server 2008 guest on Windows 7.  I can receive emails from all my accounts.  I can send email from all of my accounts EXCEPT my bluehost account (personal email).  Can't connect to the smtp server.  "The message could not be sent because the connection to smtp server box475.bluehost.com timed out".

Of course, this woks fine from the host.  If it were a password issue, I would be asked for a new password.

Suggestions?

Incidentally, I am using Thunderbird in all cases.

Comment: Does this only happen with SMTP? Can you access any other service on the same box (if there are any)?

Comment: Yes.  For instance I have an email account through Washington State University.  This also uses SMTP (smtp.wsu.edu).  I can send just fine through that SMTP server.

Comment: Oh, I meant, can you, for example access an HTTP server on `box475.bluehost.com`?